# Do I still need to defrag my hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, defragment

I've looked around and found multiple answers around the web on this. I turned off auto defrag on my Windows 7 machine because some people have told me it creates more wear and tear on the disk (using a regular magnetic platter hd), and that its also not as necessary because Windows has better file system optimization now that creates less fragments.

Is any of this true/false? Should I leave it auto on, off, or does it really even matter?

Comment: Everything you said is true, except not needing to remove the fragmentation, on a mechanical drive.

Comment: Fragment it yourself, manually, once every N months. Personally, I do it every year and should possibly do it more often but, once a year suffices for me

Comment: Windows defrags the HDD on it's own when the PC is idle. So you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is still ok to defrag a hard drive.

I have not found any reasons to believe that there is less fragmentation in modern windows than there was back in win9? or xp, they do say that, but I spent a lot of times looking at the data tossed in clusters, I assume they did not. There is no evidence to show that happening. It does get all fragmented, and even tossed all over the disk.

Much (and many) of the OS files are locked up (when in that OS). Locked files will not be defrag while the system is running, making the on-line defragmenting that windows own defragmenter does, not really efficient.  And off-line defrag, one done before the OS runs is much more complete.

[image]
This pic shows the locked files in Red, from my system, which has a number of things turned off, Give you a good idea of just how many things will not get defragged when the OS is still running. This cluster view is zoomed up, to show the data area not the unused areas.

Does it matter?  Between the large caches, the larger caches on the disk hardware itself, the speed of disks nowdays even the lower RPM drives because of increased data density, and improved methods, plus the pre-loading, the percieved performance does not change that much. Sequential reading is still much faster.

The pre-fetcher system that MS made, parts of it are dependant on the defrag process itself, allowing for the aligning of that data to be read sequentially, without that it would not be as effective at all.

One thing people like to forget when discussing the need for defragging, is disk recovery, it is much easier to un-delete files, or recover file items when the data is sequential in the next clusters. When the file tables are all gone, and your recovery software is of the lesser type the data being sequential could improve recovery chances by a lot.  (That doesn't replace needing a proper back-up)

Comment: I never really thought about the files in use by system that couldn't be defragmented until you mentioned that. Thanks for the pic and info, I might look into that program you have.

Comment: that program does not have an offline mode either, I cheat and boot into my backup os to defrag while the other OS is just a bunch of files.

Answer (score 1):

It is false. Fragementation affects the performance of your hard drive and it will do it even more as time passes by. A hard drives is continuously reading, writing and deleting data. So it can happen that logical connected data does not appear always in the same place. If you are opening a file, where your hard drive has to search for the data, it is obvious that is going to take longer.

Defragmentation is responsible for arranging the logical connected blocks again in order. It is no coincidence that Microsoft enabled auto defragmentation for hard drives by default. If you got a solid state drived installed, this option should be disabled, because it will unnecessary stress it.

Solid state drives are not affected by fragmentation, because they access and read their data electronically.

Comment: According to Microsoft employees SSDs are affected by fragmentation and Windows does automatically defrag them once a month. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheRealAndCompleteStoryDoesWindowsDefragmentYourSSD.aspx

Comment: Well you learn something new everyday I guess. :-)
Thanks for sharing!